# Connected container components further down the tree?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Currently I have a single container at the top level and state is passed via props down the tree. This is quickly becoming cumbersome and I want to have multiple container components as needed. When I try this it seems they aren't connected to the top level redux store.

Example:

App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './reduxStore';

<Provider store={store}>
  <PageContainer />
</Provider>
```

Further down the tree from PageContainer I want to have EditorContainer.tsx work

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { codeBooksAction, CodeBooksModalOptions } from '../../../actions/codeBooks';
import { Editor } from './Editor';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showModal: (opts: CodeBooksModalOptions) => dispatch(codeBooksAction(opts)),
});

export const EditorContainer = connect(
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Editor);
```

Editor.tsx

```
export interface EditorProps {
  showModal: (opts: CodeBooksModalOptions) => void;
}

export class Editor extends React.Component<EditorProps, EditorState> {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use `showModal` I get `TypeError: dispatch is not a function` from:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  showModal: (opts: CodeBooksModalOptions) => dispatch(codeBooksAction(opts)),
});
```

Do I have to do more than use `<EditorContainer />`? I shouldn't be using another `<Provider>`, right? I've had a hard time finding any examples of multiple redux-connected containers throughout an application.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` is the second argument for `connect`, the first being `mapStateToProps`. Try changing it to

```
export const EditorContainer = connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Editor);
```

If you don't need a mapStateToProps

Answer (score 0):

Two additional observations.

First, we encourage the use of multiple connected components in your app.  See the [Redux FAQ entry on connecting multiple components](https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#should-i-only-connect-my-top-component-or-can-i-connect-multiple-components-in-my-tree).

Second, `connect` supports an "object shorthand" for dispatching action creators - just pass an object full of action creators as the second argument, instead of a separate `mapDispatch` function.  So, in your case, it could be:

```
const mapDispatch = {showModal: codeBooksAction};
export const EditorContainer = connect(null, mapDispatch)(Editor)
```